# can Agfa Scala film still be processed?

Tags: processing, agfa

The title says it all.

A sub-question: does anyone still honor the Agfa Scala processing mailers sold by Color Reflections ?

P.S. I have one such mailer, that anyone here is welcome to, in the unlikely event that it has any use.   (Best I can tell, Color Reflections doesn't do anything with film anymore, barely with photography).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only can Agfa Scala be processed as negatives in a wide selection of conventional developers, Adox has recently released a Scala reversal kit that will allow you to produce B&W diapositives from nearly any B&W film, including Agfa and Adox branded Scala materials (this works best with films having a clear base, like Scala, Foma R100, and a few others).

Beyond that, I have personally processed B&W diapositives with a home process using Dektol as the first developer, a potassium dichromate and sulfuric acid bleach (hazardous material!  I'd recommend potassium permanganate or copper sulfate as alternative bleaches), and HC-110 as second developer, with light exposure for reversal.  I got good results with Tri-X (1990s vintage film, processed in 2005); I expect I'd have had better results with a film designed to be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you located? It can be [processed as negatives](https://www.peak-imaging.com/category/59-old-film-rescue). If you want slides, DR5 have their own [reversal process](http://www.agfascala.com) for B&W film including Agfa Scala. I don't think any lab is running the original Scala process anymore.

I'd [contact Color Reflections](https://colorreflections.com/contact-color-reflections/) about the mailers. I can't see why anyone would honour them now though. They are essentially just a coupon, and coupons don't have indefinite validity.

Comment: Thanks.   I was mostly just curious, having found a mailer lying around.